# SQL: Selecting from Multiple Tables and ordering

Tags: sql

I have been trying for the last hour to figure this out.

I need to see which employees work in department 10 and 30 and the location they work.  There is a table for employee which lists employee name and dept no, and a department table that is location and dept no.

Here is what i tried:

```
SELECT Departments.Location, Departments.DeptNo, Employees.Ename
FROM DEPARTMENTS, EMPLOYEES
WHERE Employees.DeptNo IN (10, 30)
Order BY Location ASC;
```

The results are screwy, for example it list employee in multiple cities when the data I entered does not reflect this.

Comment: First you need to Google `join` to see how to stop the screwyness. Then you need to Google `Group By` to learn how to add up the numbers.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are generating a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Your existing query does not have any `JOIN` condition between the two tables. You need to `JOIN` the tables:

```
SELECT d.Location, d.DeptNo, e.Ename
FROM DEPARTMENTS d
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES e
    on d.deptno = e.deptno
WHERE e.DeptNo IN (10, 30)
Order BY Location ASC;
```

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e266/1)

INNER Join Result:

```
| LOCATION | DEPTNO | ENAME |
-----------------------------
|     Loc2 |     10 |  emp2 |
|     Loc2 |     10 |  emp3 |
|     Loc3 |     30 |  emp6 |
|     Loc3 |     30 |  emp4 |
|     Loc3 |     30 |  emp5 |
```

A Cartesian query where you are not using `JOIN` syntax will produce a result like this (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e266/4)):

```
| LOCATION | DEPTNO | ENAME |
-----------------------------
|     Loc1 |      1 |  emp6 |
|     Loc1 |      1 |  emp4 |
|     Loc1 |      1 |  emp2 |
|     Loc1 |      1 |  emp5 |
|     Loc1 |      1 |  emp3 |
|     Loc2 |     10 |  emp3 |
|     Loc2 |     10 |  emp6 |
|     Loc2 |     10 |  emp4 |
|     Loc2 |     10 |  emp2 |
|     Loc2 |     10 |  emp5 |
|     Loc3 |     30 |  emp3 |
|     Loc3 |     30 |  emp6 |
|     Loc3 |     30 |  emp4 |
|     Loc3 |     30 |  emp2 |
|     Loc3 |     30 |  emp5 |
```

If you want to use commas between your then you **must** include the join condition in the `WHERE` clause and this will produce the same result as the `INNER JOIN` version:

```
select d.Location, d.DeptNo, e.ename
from departments d, employees e
WHERE e.DeptNo IN (10, 30)
   and d.deptno = e.deptno
Order BY Location ASC;
```

Comment: maybe im a little confused,according to the OP, the employee table already has the dept no. , so why is the join reqd?

Comment: @SajjanSarkar there might be a column that is similar between the two tables but if you don't join on them, then you are multiplying each table row by row which will skew the results.

Comment: This was correct.  The original query I tried returned 36 values.  When I amended the query to include join it returned the correct results.  Thank you.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar see my edit as to the difference in the results using a `JOIN` and a comma separated table list without a join condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Departments.Location, Departments.DeptNo, Employees.Ename
FROM DEPARTMENTS JOIN EMPLOYEES ON (Departments.DeptNo = Employees.DeptNo)
WHERE Employees.DeptNo IN (10, 30)
Order BY Location ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't join the tables with the primary-foreign so you got a Cartesian result  :

```
SELECT Departments.Location, Departments.DeptNo, Employees.Ename
FROM DEPARTMENTS, EMPLOYEES
WHERE Employees.DeptNo IN (10, 30)
AND   Employees.DeptNo = DEPARTMENTS.DeptNo -- <-------
Order BY Location ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of pointless now, but the comments are fun:

Orignal Requirement

```
Select
  Count(*)
From
  Employees e
Where
  e.DeptNo In (10, 30)
```

Clarified Requirement

```
Select
  *
From
  Employees e
Where
  e.DeptNo In (10, 30)
```

Good that you learned something about joins, but you still don't appear to need them to answer this? Only now you're going to say you also need their locations? Damn me and my psychic abilities. Just as to not copy another answer. (please don't use this in reality)

```
Select
  (select
     d.location 
   from
     departments d 
   where
     d.deptno = e.deptno
  ) as Department,
  e.*
From
  Employees e
Where
  e.DeptNo In (10, 30)
```

Look still no joins! (not really)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e266/7

Comment: this wont work as it will give the total for depts 10,30.. not the COUNTS for each one

Comment: @SajjanSarkar English isn't that precise. "I need to how many employees work in department 10 and 30" could mean in total, or each separately. I picked the easiest. It could even mean that employees can work in multiple departments, and you want to know how many are in 10 and 30.

Comment: fair enough, actually now uve confused me abt what the OP wants lol

Comment: My apologies, it should have read:

I need to know _which_ employees work in departments 10 and 30.

Comment: This won't work because they need the location which is stored in the `departments` table.

Comment: @bluefeet that's only because you're basing it on the SQL he tried. Look at the requirement in English "I need to know which employees work in departments 10 and 30", ah bugger question has been updated again.

Comment: actually no I am not basing it on that _I need to see which employees work in department 10 and 30 and the location they work._

Comment: Even though it was a revision, you just proved that this is not a correct solution.